# Authentication moving from Couchbase Server 4 to 5

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

I'm migrating over from Couchbase Server 4.x to Couchbase Server 5.x. I understand that there is a new user-based authentication. But it's not clear to me how I should be using `ClusterHelper` since there is no longer a password for the bucket.

Previously:

```
// at app startup
ClusterHelper.Initialize(new ClientDefinition { ... });

// later in DAL
var cluster = ClusterHelper.GetBucket("bucketname", "bucketpassword");
```

But now, using 5.x, there's no longer a bucket password. Where do I enter the user credentials?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new overload to `ClusterHelper.Initialize` with an `IAuthenticator` parameter.

So now, for example:

```
// at app startup
ClusterHelper.Initialize(new ClientDefinition { ... }, new PasswordAuthenticator("username", "password"));

// then later in the your data access:
var cluster = ClusterHelper.GetBucket("bucketname");
```

[Here's the overload](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/master/Src/Couchbase/ClusterHelper.cs#L276) in the ClusterHelper.cs

If you were using Web.config previously, you may also have to change that. The password is no longer on the `<bucket />` node, it's now on the `<couchbase />` node. See [this answer in the forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/createmanager-using-credentials-from-app-config/15078/4).